JPA with generic Collection?
I am building a project that has a quite specific design.
I have 5 entity classes that are really similar. So I created a super class to avoid code redundance.
Here is the super class:
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class SuperClass<T extends SomeCommonEntity> {

    @Id
    private Integer field1;

    private String field2;

    private String field3;

    private Integer field4;

    @OneToMany
    private T[] genericField;

    public SuperClass() {
    }

    public SuperClass(Integer field1, String field2, Integer field4) {
        this.field1 = id;
        this.field2 = name;
        this.field4 = upperDivisionId;
    }

    public SuperClass(Integer field1, String field2, Integer field4, String field3) {
        this(field1, field2, field4);
        this.geojson = geoJson;
    }
}

And here is one of the child class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "child1_table")
@AttributeOverride(name = "field4", column = @Column(name = "field4_custom_name"))
@AssociationOverride(name = "genericField", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "custom_generic_field_id")
})
public class ChildClass1 extends SuperClass<ChildClass1GenericFieldType> {
}

Important information to know:

Each child class have their own table in the database
only the field4 name differs in the database, that is why I am overriding it in the child class
to simplify the example, the genericField collection from the super class is another entity class (=> another table) that is a detail of the child class (child1_table have its corresponding child1_detail_table, for each child class, there is a detail class)

To better clarify the example:

Child1Class has Child1DetailsClass
The table child1_detail_table has the child1_table id as a reference

Again, only the mapping column differs for each child class, that is why I am only overriding the association to modify the @JoinColumn for each of them.
This made me create a super non-repository bean:
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SuperRepository<T extends SuperClass<?>> {

    @Query("SELECT new package.SuperClass(a.field1, a.field2, a.field4, a.field3) FROM #{#entityName} a")
    List<T> findAllWithoutGenericField();

    @Query("SELECT new package.SuperClass(a.field1, a.field2, a.field4) FROM #{#entityName} a")
    List<T> findAllWithoutField4AndGenericResult();

}

This is why I did not make the SuperClass abstract because I need the constructor in the JPQL @Query.
I still need to create a repository for each child class but this way, I am only adding custom method in this super repository and every child take profit of the inheritance.
Everything worked perfectly fine until I needed to add this genericField collection.
This is the error:
2024-09-27T10:10:50.789+03:00 ERROR 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
2024-09-27T10:10:50.789+03:00  WARN 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
2024-09-27T10:10:50.789+03:00  INFO 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-09-27T10:10:50.804+03:00  INFO 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-09-27T10:10:50.804+03:00  INFO 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-09-27T10:10:50.842+03:00  INFO 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-09-27T10:10:50.869+03:00 ERROR 7952 --- [app] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at package.AppName.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.getSignatureType(AttributeFactory.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.buildAttribute(MetadataContext.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.processJpa(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        ... 24 common frames omitted

This error only fire when the generic collection is present.
The main reason I kept it this way is that is because of the super repository. Yes I can omit the genericField and put it in each child to avoid this problem but this also mean, I have to create a custom @Query in each child repository to tell JPA to wether fetch or not the collection field (making it redundant for all the child repository, and JPA will ignore those custom @Query if I am using the super repository)
Sorry if this is too long but my real question is, how can I implement such design or am I doing something work that JPA does not support ?
